# Google App Engine & Java : images thumb

Tags: java, google-app-engine, resize, thumbnails

I'm trying to resize and crop images into Google App engine in order to create thumbnails

I would like to be able to create 200x150 thumbs from any size.

This is the code I'm using so far now I need to crop it so it doesn't go bigger than 200x150:

```
    Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(picture);
    //Create the Image Service Factory and the Resize Transform
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;
    if (oldImage.getWidth() > oldImage.getHeight()) {
        w = 1000;
        h = height;
    } else {
        h = 1000;
        w = width;
    }
    Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(w, h);
    //Resize The Image using the transform created above
    Image resizedImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, oldImage);

    Transform crop = ImagesServiceFactory.makeCrop(0.0, 0.0, width / resizedImage.getHeight(), height / resizedImage.getHeight());

    Image cropedImage = imagesService.applyTransform(crop, resizedImage);

    //Serve the newly transformed image
    return cropedImage.getImageData();
```

Thanks !

Comment: what exception are you getting? print out stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I serve thumbnails with google app engine dynamically using [getServingUrl](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html#getServingUrl%28com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey%29)

That can resize and crop storing only one image doing the resize and crop dynamically. Since I'm very satisfied with that solution I hope it can work for you too.

Comment: Unfortunately my pictures are stored into the datastore, I don't think I can use that function with those blobs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `oldImage` is less than 200px wide.